# Where is the table/view script generated and how to get it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have written a Create Table script in a query window and run it. So the table got created. Now, where is this script file being generated (system table). I mean if I do a

```
select * from sys.syscomments
```

I will get the script for stored procedure or function in the "Text" column. Likewise any way of getting the same for table or view?

Any DMV etc...

Thanks in advance

Comment: uh.. `create table` script creates a table, it does not store itself i believe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the script is stored, but if you're looking to be able to view the scripted language to create the table, in SQL2008 R2 (and I'm pretty sure SQL2008) SSMS can generate the script on the fly.  Just select your Table (or View, SP, etc...) and right click.  From the context menu, choose Script Table as Create To (or whatever other modification you choose from the list).  Then you have a choice of output locations-the New Query Editor Window is probably easiest to see your results.  From there you have the base language for that table's creation and you can modify or save it from there.

Answer (score 0):

below query is also works for views

```
select * from sys.syscomments
```

For getting script of tables , you have to

```
Right Click on database >> tasks >> Generate Scripts >> choose objects (select tables)
```

I think that is the possible way of getting table scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For views you can use the column `VIEW_DEFINITION` in:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

I don't think there is an equivalent for tables because tables don't require a stored definition because the table itself is the definition. If you need to copy table structures then the best method is probably to use:

```
SELECT   *
INTO     NewTable
FROM     OldTable
WHERE    0 = 1
```

You could try generating your own scripts using the system views and creating dynamic SQL, something like [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/script-table-definitions-using-tsql/431) would get you started

This does not create constraints, and there maybe things I've missed, or cause it to break but the general gist is there. You could also do this outside of SQL as demonstrated quite nicely [In this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274401/invoke-sql-script-wizard-programmatically).

**HOWEVER** I should add I do not condone the use of these methods. There are few scenarios I can think of where it would be necessary to programatically copy a tables structure in this fashion. If it is necessary to copy structures as a one off you'd be better off doing this using the generate script functions that are built into SSMS.